# Javascript assigning object values to new object

Tags: javascript, oop

So I am using options to pass values to a new object in a literal object fashion.

```
var obj = new myObject({height:'500',width:'300');


function myObject(options){

}
```

I'm not sure the best route to get these values assigned to the object though so that this would work.

```
 function myObject(options){

...assignment...   

alert(this.width);

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function myObject(options){

   // copy the options into the current object
   for (var key in options) {
       if (options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           this[key] = options[key];
       }
   }

   alert(this.width);     // 300
}

var obj = new myObject({height:'500',width:'300'});
```

You can even an *extend* this concept where you can have *default* property values `myObject`, and you can override them with `options` object:

```
function myObject(options){
    // DEFAULTS
    this.name = 'Box';
    this.width = '100';
    this.height = '100';

   // copy the options into the current object
   for (var key in options) {
       if (options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           this[key] = options[key];
       }
   }

   alert(this.width); 
}

var obj = new myObject({height:'500',width:'300'});     // alert: 300
var obj2 = new myObject({height: '500'});               // alert: 100
```

Comment: I know the OP didn't say anything about "default" options, but it wouldn't be a bad idea to include some default object, with the keys that should always be assigned to the object, no matter if they're provided in `options` or not.

Comment: @wilco Yes these properties are public, unless OP wanted to keep them private, there are plenty of other answers on SO that explain how to make private variables in objects.

Comment: @sweetamylase Not that it's any better, but this is what I was thinking - http://jsfiddle.net/XpSXv/1/